# What is the difference between an N-MOS FET and a tri-state buffer?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, nmos, tri-state

Is an N-MOS FET an equivalent of a tri-state buffer, where the source is the input, the gate is the enable, and the drain is the output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is hard to tell? I think the question is well-worded; please point out any part that's not clear and I'm happy to fix it.

Comment: @SnySmartie It's not clear. It's like asking what the difference is between a wheel and a bicycle. *(An nfet might be part of a tristate buffer.)*

Comment: No, not at all. A buffer has current gain due to a usually complementary output stage, where a single NMOS FET as you describe would not.  Also, the input voltage levels would be logic-family compatible for the gate, but probably not for the FET.

Comment: @periblepsis Well the answer is that a wheel is not the equivalent of the bicycle. I have specifically stated whether the two are equivalents, and also used "**an** nMOS" for both my title and my question.

Comment: @Sny  What prompted your question?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: A MOSFET is a single transitor.  A tri-state buffer is a circuit that may contain several MOSFETs.

Comment: @SnySmartie Yes. A wheel is not equivalent to a bicycle. And you have your answer. They are different and one may be a part of the other in some circumstances. But it isn't even necessary for a nFET to be part of a tristate buffer. A tristate buffer can be done with BJTs, just fine. You can draw your conclusions now.

Comment: @SnySmartie I have edited my respond to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let me address what they are first before answering your question. Technically, an N-channel MOSFET (NMOS) is not equivalent to a Tri-State buffer. The latter is more complex and is built using several MOSFETs (assuming we are talking about the CMOS version of tri-state buffer).

The following are the simplified models of an [NMOS and a Tri-state buffer](http://tinyurl.com/yqtfe8h4) represented by switches just to convey the concepts across and to show their ***behavioral*** similarities and differences.
[image]

Both have an input and an output, but the tri-state buffer has a control input which enables/disables the output. For the models above, you give the inputs by clicking on the switches.

The NMOS is either connected to GND or disconnected from it. The Tri-state buffer is slightly more complex.

The name [tri-state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic) comes from its properties of having 3 stable states, namely, *high output state*, *low output state*, and *high-impedance state*. When the switch is connected to the +5V supply, its output will be driven to a high state*. When the switch is connected to the GND, its output will be driven to a low state*. When the enable switch is open, then its internal circuit is disconnected from the output terminal, so the output will neither be driven high nor low and therefore remains in high-impedance state (or Hi-Z or floating).

[* assuming the *Enable* switch is closed]

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/yw2pyafs) are 2 circuits using NMOS that you can play around with.
[image]
By clicking on the switches, you will see the left circuit turning ON/OFF the red LED, but the LED of the circuit on the right will not light up no matter whether the switch is closed or open.

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/ymt447lq) are 2 similar circuits using Tri-state buffers.
[image]

By clicking on the switches, you will see the left and right circuits turning ON/OFF their respective LEDs, except that they are opposite to one another. The table below summarizes the results.
[image]

Note that when the Enable switch is open, both LEDs remain OFF. This is because the output cannot be driven high or low no matter what input you give.

On the practical side, a tri-state buffer is only used for signaling and is never used for driving a heavy load (but suitable for driving tiny loads like LEDs). Whereas the MOSFET, in general, can be categorized as a small signal, medium power, or high power type. The last 2 types are meant to drive medium and heavy loads. Most MOSFETs are general purpose, but some are designed for RF.

Also the rated voltage for tri-state buffer is low (commonly <~5V, but CD4xxxx are <~20V) and the rated voltage for MOSFET can be up to 800V or higher.

**Edited**

> Is an N-MOS FET an equivalent of a tri-state buffer, where the source is the input, the gate is the enable, and the drain is the output?

Technically, they are different as I have explained above. However, in the configuration you mentioned, it might appear to **behave** like a tri-state buffer. Unfortunately, it does not. Read on if you want to know why.

Before I go ahead to answer, here are some basic properties of NMOS. [First](http://tinyurl.com/yoaa83ga), the VG of the NMOS needs to be appropriately biased to turn the NMOS on.
[image]

By default, both NMOS VGS thresholds are 1.5V in this simulator. On the left, the MOSFET is turned on with the Drain current of 4.8mA because its VGS > VGS(thres). On the right the current is nearly 0A because VGS < VGS(thres) (the non-zero current is due to a very tiny leakage current). Therefore: **Property 1: To turn on the NMOS, VGS needs to be higher than VGS(thres), i.e., VG > VS + VGS(thres).**

Second, the majority of the MOSFETs sold has its body (substrate) connected to the Source terminal, so you get a body diode that will conduct current from Source to Drain if the Source voltage is greater than the Drain voltage by more than the diode forward voltage. The following [circuit](http://tinyurl.com/yom8vexe) demonstrates this.

[image]

The body diode of the NMOS is present, but it is not drawn in the Falstad simulator. **Property 2: The drain current flows from Source to Drain when VS > VD + Vf, even the VG < VS + VGS(thres)**, where Vf is the diode forward voltage that is ~0.7V. Note that when VG < VS + VGS(thres), the MOSFET is off; the current flows through the diode and does not change for \$0V \le \textrm{VG} \le 6.5V\$.

Now, we are ready to address the question. The following are the results for [circuit](http://tinyurl.com/ytdqkh26) with the load connected to the output and GND. There are 4 different combinations of input + enable. The diode is explicitly added on the NMOS to show the intrinsic body diode.
[image]

Note that due to **Property 1**, the *Enable* terminal needs to be >6.5V (VGS(thres) = 1.5V) to allow VS to be driven high close to 5V when the *Input* terminal is 5V (see top left circuit). In my simulation, I set it to 10V to ensure that the NMOS is fully on. The four results show that it exhibits the tri-state properties in this configuration.

The following are the results for [circuit](http://tinyurl.com/yl7ez7qk) with the load connected to the output and +5V.
[image]

When the Input terminal is 0V and the Enable terminal is 0V (disabled), we expect the LED to be off since the output should go Hi-Z. But the result shows that the LED is on (see bottom right circuit). It is on because of **Property 2**. This demonstrates that it fails to exhibit the tri-state properties in this configuration. We can fix this by using 2 NMOS back-to-back, but I digress.

So what do we learn from this?

1. The NMOS with its Drain as Input, Gate as Enable, and Source as
   Output fails to exhibit the tri-state properties. (So this
   answers your question.)
2. You need to feed the Enable terminal (Gate) with a higher voltage
   than the Input terminal in order to ensure the Output can be driven
   to the voltage level of the Input. This is a nuisance.
3. Tri-state buffer is a "buffer" gate, but yours is not a "buffer"
   gate. In fact, it behaves more like a "passthrough" gate. This
   means the input needs to be strong signal to drive the heavier
   output load because the input is directly driving the output load.
   For a buffer gate, the input can be a weak signal even
   you have a heavier load at the output.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no.

A basic CMOS output has a PMOS device to pull the output up, and an NMOS device to pull it down.

A tri-state buffer has the means to turn both of those devices off. A simple inverter has one of them turned on - or another. The third state of a tri-state buffer is when neither output device is on. Since the output isn’t driven, it can assume any state imposed by external drive sources.

The fourth possible state is when both devices are on at the same time and there’s a shoot-through current from positive to negative supply. This dissipates quite a bit of power. In high-voltage or high-strentgh drivers this fourth state ends up in smoke after a short while. So it’s not desirable to say the least. But usually it is unavoidable and many CMOS digital circuits have a bit of shoot-through when they switch states.